# unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847

Tags: git, macos, github

when I clone from github recently, the terminal output is "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847", and it works were before, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This could come from different things:

- Most probably github upgrade their supported ciphersuite, and you need to upgrade your git version.
- An active proxy is between you and the github server, and is using an outdated SSL version. You're out of luck.

Also, the port it's trying to connect with to github.com (-9847) seems a bit odd. It could be some kind of config file corruption. Double check your `git config -l`

Comment: Thank you for answering me.I used a VPN,maybe this is the reason for the problem. When I quit VPN,and try cloning again, here is the log: "fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out". What's wrong?

Comment: Here I paste the log of my `git config -l`:
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
core.pager=less -r
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true

Comment: alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'

Comment: alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit

Comment: alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\  => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=MyNameIsWood
user.email=liubaishan_ios@163.com
http.sslverify=false

Comment: Thank you.I work it out finally. I am behind a proxy. Using `git config --global http.proxy http[s]://proxyUserName:proxyPassword@proxyIP:proxyPort`